# Unable to login to super user from normal user

Tags: login, root, users

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 with no problem. But after login as a normal user, I am unable to switch to super user(using "su" command). Its showing "Authentication failure"
plz help me..

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo su
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu and other Debian-based systems, by default `root` user has no password set, so it is impossible to log in directly as root or to become root by using `su` command.

Instead, Ubuntu uses `sudo` command which allows much more flexible management of permissions - users can perform administrative tasks without knowing root password.

While it is possible to give root user a password, it is not necessary and not recommended.

You can see my answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/difference-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i) for more details.

In short, when you need to get root console, you type

```
sudo su
```

and then enter *your own* password. More often, if you want to run a single command as superuser, you just type

```
sudo command
```

and, again, enter *your own* password

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo su
```

in a terminal, after you type your login password, will turn you root. After this, you can give the command

```
passwd
```

which will allow you to give a new password for root (this will not alter your login password). This is the password that you will type every time you use the

```
su
```

command, because it will be taken as it is the super user's password.

Comment: Giving `root` a password is not a normal or recommended practice in Ubuntu. Instead of showing how to shoot himself in the foot to a user who clearly does not understand how things work in Ubuntu, you could've explained how to do it properly.