# Why do I get "Authentication Failure"?

Tags: authentication, permissions

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10.

As i started the terminal and ran the command `su` which we usually use to perform root operations and to get the # symbol.

After running the command it asks me to enter password, I entered the password which Ubuntu had asked me during installation.

I entered the password many times , but it gives me a message **Authentication Failure**

What should i do ???

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: in Ubuntu the root account is disabled, so you **cannot** log in as root or use `su -` to become root.

Instead (as the user who was created during installation) use `sudo <command-you-want-to-issue`, after which you are prompted for **your** password and the command is executed with root priviledges.

Please read more about the ideas behind this in the question [Differences between su and sudo...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/difference-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i)

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu installer never asks you to enter a **root** password, it only asks for a **user** password. This is in contrast with many other distros, for example Debian, which will ask you for both.

The Ubuntu installer only asks for a user password. It grants special permission for this user so that it will be able to run any and all programs with `sudo`.

In Ubuntu the root user is disabled by default, whenever you need to run something as root you should run it with `sudo`. This is not a limitation, as you are still able to do all the same things as when you used `su`, just slightly differently.