# How to create a .bz2 file from a directory without using tar?

Tags: format, compression

I've been searching on the internet and used Archiver to make .bz2 files. My archiving tool only makes tar.bz2 and my game host doesn't read that. It reads .bz2 files only. Is there a way to make a DIRECTORY into a .bz2 file?

I've tried `sudo bzip2` but it doesn't accept directories.

Comment: What do you mean your game host doesn't read it?

Comment: I recommend reading up on what sudo is for e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/difference-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i

Comment: Also telling us which game you are talking about wouldn't hurt, rather benefit your question, because it would be much clearer what content the game/application expects to be in such compressed files.

Answer (score 1):

No; bzip2 and the other compression utilities only compress a single file, so if you want to archive multiple files you need another tool like tar first, then compress the archive.