# What is the difference between sudo -i and sudo -s?

Tags: command-line, sudo

I am a new Ubuntu user and find some people tell me to use `sudo -i` to get root and others tell me to use `sudo -s`. What is the difference? Which one do I use and when?

Answer (score 12):

The major difference between `sudo -i` and `sudo -s` is:

- `sudo -i` gives you the root environment, i.e. your `~/.bashrc` is ignored.
- `sudo -s` gives you the user's environment, so your `~/.bashrc` is respected.

Here is an example, you can see that I have an application `lsl` in my `~/.bin/` directory which is accessible via `sudo -s` but not accessible with `sudo -i`. Note also that the Bash prompt changes as will with `sudo -i` but not with `sudo -s`:

```
dotancohen@melancholy:~$ ls .bin
lsl

dotancohen@melancholy:~$ which lsl
/home/dotancohen/.bin/lsl

dotancohen@melancholy:~$ sudo -i

root@melancholy:~# which lsl

root@melancholy:~# exit
logout

dotancohen@melancholy:~$ sudo -s
Sourced .bashrc

dotancohen@melancholy:~$ which lsl
/home/dotancohen/.bin/lsl

dotancohen@melancholy:~$ exit
exit
```

Though `sudo -s` is convenient for giving you the environment that you are familiar with, **I recommend the use of `sudo -i`** for two reasons:

1. The visual reminder that you are in a 'root' session.
2. The root environment is far less likely to be poisoned with malware, such as a rogue line in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Bash prompt does change with `sudo -s` unless you have placed something setting `$PS1` in an unusual way in one of the initialization scripts. Tested on GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1) (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) and Sudo version 1.8.21p2

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo -i
```

```
-i [command]
                 The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell speci‐
                 fied by the password database entry of the target user as a
                 login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files
                 such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a
                 command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution
                 via the shell's -c option.  If no command is specified, an
                 interactive shell is executed.  sudo attempts to change to
                 that user's home directory before running the shell.  The
                 security policy shall initialize the environment to a minimal
                 set of variables, similar to what is present when a user logs
                 in.  The Command Environment section in the sudoers(5) manual
                 documents how the -i option affects the environment in which
                 a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.
```

```
sudo -s
```

```
 -s [command]
                 The -s (shell) option runs the shell specified by the SHELL
                 environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified
                 in the password database.  If a command is specified, it is
                 passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.
                 If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.
```

Comment: Additional info: you can also check the `man` page `man sudo` for more information.