# Now do I get super user privileges?

Tags: users

I am new to Linux so I need to find out how to get super user privileges so I can install Simplify3D?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: welcome to askubuntu. you can get super user privilege by adding sudo before the command you r using.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/what-are-the-differences-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i-sudo-su

Answer (score 2):

In Linux (and Unix in general), there is a SuperUser named root. The Windows equivalent of root is the Administrators group. The SuperUser can do anything and everything, and thus doing daily work as the SuperUser can be dangerous. You could type a command incorrectly and destroy the system. Ideally, you run as a user that has only the privileges needed for the task at hand. In some cases, this is necessarily root, but most of the time it is a regular user.

By default, the root account password is locked in Ubuntu. This means that you cannot login as root directly or use the su command to become the root user. However, since the root account physically exists it is still possible to run programs with root-level privileges. This is where sudo comes in - it allows authorized users (normally "Administrative" users) to run certain programs as root without having to know the root password.

This means that in the terminal you should use sudo for commands that require root privileges; simply prepend sudo to all the commands you need to run as root. For more extensive usage examples, please see below. Similarly, when you run GUI programs that require root privileges (e.g. the network configuration applet), use graphical sudo (gksudo) and you will also be prompted for a password. Just remember, when sudo asks for a password, it needs YOUR USER password, and not the root account password.

Please refer to this link for a tutorial about sudo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPDrKrDbzys

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Answer (score 0):

If I may ask how will you install it? If it is through the Graphical User Interface, it will request the admin password which you registered upon installation. If you will use a terminal and commands write sudo command (your command will be `sudo apt-get install name.of.app` if it is your added repositories or the default Ubuntu repositories). Then it will ask for the password that you registered upon installation. Hope this helps!