# Command "sudo su" is not working

Tags: bash, login, root

By mistake my bashrc has changed (using source command to a .com file). Now sudo su command is not working. To use root I have to give bash command. How can I return previous stage? Or use sudo su?

Comment: you can check this question if you looking for equivalent http://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/what-are-the-differences-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i-sudo-su

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Also, I think you should be using `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su`