# Need root privileges to access files on USB flash drive

Tags: permissions, sudo, usb-drive

It wont let me open the flash drive to get the files I need. Anyone know the line of code I need to put me as root. I would like to stay root.

Comment: Running `sudo su` will keep you as root. Use with caution.

Comment: `sudo su root` will make you the root user on command line. However, I'm guessing you probably just need to change the owner of the mounted flash drive, which should be located under /media/username/drivename. In the cli from /media/username you can run `sudo chown -R username drivename` which should make it accessible to you from the Ubuntu GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is designed so you don't need to be *root*; instead you do

```
sudo -i
```

inside a terminal emulator window which bestows the rights of *root*.

However, it's safer to use

```
sudo *commmandtoexecute*
```

as needed; for example, if you want to open the file manager in Ubuntu with the rights of *root*, do

```
sudo nautilus
```

A good explanation of the options available with sudo, can be found in the answers at [What are the differences between "su", "sudo -s", "sudo -i", "sudo su"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/what-are-the-differences-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i-sudo-su)

And, this is done for user safety and administrator sanity. *root* is just too powerful and it's far too easy to break a system and/or destroy data to be in *root* all the time.

Comment: Please advice `sudo -i` over `sudo su`. The 1st will log events as the user and not as root.

Comment: i want to stay root forever is there a line of code that can make me root forever?

Comment: "Stay root forever" == "I will NEVER make a mistake or typo". 50 years