# using ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS version vikas@vikas-X542UQ:~$ apt --fix-broken install E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

Tags: files, lock

[image: I have used sudo -s for update but still facing problem due to unmet dependencies packages]

Problem facing in

```
sudo apt-get update
```

tried

```
sudo -s
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

then facing problem

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-base : Depends: libreoffice-common (>= 1:6.4.0~beta1-2~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.4.7) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-bsh : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-js : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-python : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Use `sudo` instead of loging in as root with `sudo -s`. https://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/what-are-the-differences-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i-sudo-su

Comment: I see package `libreoffice-common | 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.8            | focal-security   | all` available, so check the output from your commands (starting with `sudo apt update`, no warnings/errors or missing lines etc)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-base : Depends: libreoffice-common (>= 1:6.4.0~beta1-2~) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.4.7) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-bsh : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-js : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-script-provider-python : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, as the computer suggests. If it shows `Could not open lockfile`, then reboot and try again.

Comment: Not Answer workable

Comment: What did not work?

Comment: After apt --fix-broken install

Comment: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)

Comment: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: Use `sudo apt --fix-broken install `. You missed sudo. If you encounter the same error despite using sudo, then restart the computer and try again